# clear cache in Nightmare.js (Electron)

Tags: javascript, local-storage, electron, nightmare

I'm using nightmare js to log into a site that sets a token in local storage. However, any future tests I run the user is already logged in. I'm guessing the local storage wasn't cleared. Is there any way to do this? My code in **test.js**

```
require('mocha-generators').install();

var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('test login', function() {
  var nightmare = Nightmare({show: true})

  after(function*() {
    yield nightmare.end();
  })

  it('should login given right credentials', function*() {
    this.timeout(50000);
    console.log("running test");
    var link = yield nightmare
      .goto('http://127.0.0.1:3000/login')
      .wait(1000)
      .type('.email-field', 'username@email.com')
      .type('.password-field', 'password')
      .click('.login button')
      .wait(1000)

  });
})
```

I run the test using: **mocha**

the test runs fine and closes. However when I run again the user starts off as logged in. Is there anyway to clear the cache or local storage in nightmarejs?

Electron has a way to clear session info via `session.clearCache` (http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.32.0/api/session/) but I don't know how to access the session object from nightmare.

Comment: Did you figure it out ? Just wondering. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixG answered below

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alright figured it out, we can use Electrons 'web-preferences' property.

```
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: false,
  webPreferences: {
    partition: 'nopersist'
  }
});
```

when initiating nightmare use 'web-prefences' partition property to handle sessions. more info here: https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md. The gist of is as follows:

> the page will use a persistent session available to all pages in the app with the same partition. if there is no persist: prefix, the page will use an in-memory session.

so basically if you init nightmare as:

```
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: false,
  webPreferences: {
    partition: 'persist:derp'
  }
});
```

then the session will persist under 'derp', this can be helpful when you are testing features inside authenticated routes. (derp isn't significant, can be anything following **persist:**)

if you don't want session to persist don't use **persist:**. I use **nopersist** but this could be any string that isn't prefixed by **persist:**

**EDIT:** `show:false` isn't significant to session, it just shows what electron (which nightmare uses) is doing if you set `show:true`, but this line can be removed

Comment: It seems the property name is actually webPreferences, not web-preferences

Comment: depends on the version of nightmare, they might have updated it for newer version.

Comment: Maksim hi5! webPreferences it is

Comment: @Saad update your answer. The correct property is now `webPreferences`.

Comment: i dont get it, By default nightmare will create an in-memory partition for each instance. This means that any localStorage or cookies or any other form of persistent state will be DESTROYED when nightmare is ended.